# Jekyll watch not working with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, jekyll

I am trying to use [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) with [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and for some reason when I try to use the `jekyll serve -w` command it will start the server and build everything fine, but when I try and edit a file it will not rebuild.

Comment: You need to give us more information. Particularly, any code that is not working. It is hard to help you when we can't see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 2.0.0 [1] of Jekyll you can use `--force_polling` with `--watch` in order for Jekyll to pick up changes outside of Vagrant.

[1] https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/History.markdown

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OS X with python v2.7.6 (check with `python -V`) you need to downgrade to 2.7:

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
echo 'if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
pyenv install 2.7
pyenv global 2.7
```